# Insert a div after a tr

Tags: php, jquery, html

I´m doing a page that checks the availability of hotels and cabins.
I do the php query and the result shows me which hotels and cabins are available. But this was made with tables.

What I need is to place each div after the tr(all divs and tr of results have the same class, separately) so in that div I´ll show a map(google maps) with the address of the hotel and some pictures of it. The class of the divs is .slide and the class of the tr is .slide-toggle.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.slide').css("display", "none");
      var table = document.getElementById("tablita");
      for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
           $(table.rows[i]).click(function(){
       $('.slide').slideToggle('fast').append('<tr class="slide-toggle"></tr>');
                //iterate through rows
                //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop 
      
           });
         }
          });
    </script>
```

```html
    echo "<tr class='slide-toggle'>"; ?>
    <?php
      
      //if($disponibilidad !="COMPLETO"){

    ?>
<td>
  <div align='left' class="Estilo11"><span class='style1'><?PHP  echo utf8_encode($row['Establecimiento']) ?></span></div>
</td>
<td>
  <div align='left' class="Estilo11"><span class='style1'><?PHP  echo utf8_encode($row['Categoria']) ?></span></div>
</td>
<td>
  <div align='left' class="Estilo11"><span class='style1'><?php  echo $row['Direccion'] ?></span></div>
</td>
<td>
  <div align='left' class="Estilo11"><span class='style1'><?php  echo utf8_encode($row['Telefono']) ?></span></div>
</td>
<td>
  <div align='left' class="Estilo11"><span class='style1'><?PHP  echo $disponibilidad ?></span></div>
</td>

<?PHP
  echo" </tr>";
  echo "<tr class='slide'><div class='slide1'></div></tr>";
  echo"<td>&nbsp;</td>";
  echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
  echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
```

What is happening, is that when I click the tr, all the divs open together, but before the table. I need that when I click the tr, the div opens (only the one that correspond to that tr) after the tr to bring the correct information to the user.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot add div after the table row (tr) if it isn't part of the table. Everything outside of  gets placed in the wrong place.

Here's a working code (and JSFiddle) which does the thing you want.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("tr.slide-toggle").on("click",function() {
  $(this).find(".slide").show();
});
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g61sobyg/4/

Comment: Thanks! But it´s not what I need. I need that div after the tr.
Just like this: http://www.fehgra.org.ar/capacitacion/oferta

Comment: I fixed it. I´ve put the div inside a tr, but now I need that when I click the second row(if I have more than 1 result from the query), only the second new tr shows because all the new tr´s open at the same time, when I click only one of the old tr.

Comment: Please, would you help me? @Jannunen

Comment: This jsfiddle would be closer to your needs [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qcpe2rs3/3/)

Comment: @FrancoMarziano, If you are doing something like in the link you mentioned, I would maybe do the page structure differently. For example:

    <div class="container">
        <table class="info_de_hacienda">...</table>
        <div class="mapandinfo">...</div>
    </div>

Comment: That it was only an example of the effect.

What I really need is to identify each .slide-toggle, so that when I click on one of the .slide-toggle tr´s, it opens only one .slide and not all and when I close(clicking on it) the one it´s open, I close only one and only I can click the one that is open. How can I do that?

Comment: Thanks!! It worked!! I modified the code, because it was too static.

https://jsfiddle.net/jhjgpmzn/1/